# Misbehaving footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a footer that stays on the bottom all right. But I noticed that when I scroll it goes over some elements but it goes under other element which looks super odd. I don't understand why that is.

```
footer {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 0%, #000066 100%);
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-color: #060675;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

I'd like to have a footer that goes over all content. Is this about positioning `absolute` and `relative`. It could be because some elements are positioned relatively and some I didn't specify thus it's positioned relatively by default and yet the footer goes over and not under.

How can I go about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to add z-index which handles the layers in CSS..

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.

An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

```css
footer {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 0%, #000066 100%);
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-color: #060675;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10; /* higher the number the more upper layer it will go*/
    bottom: 0;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
  }
```